# Can't access file in .jar via URL

Tags: java, file, jar

I need to access a file inside the currently executed .jar using a URL.

```
URL url = BlockConverter.class.getResource("/test.txt");
System.out.println(url.toString());
InputStream  is = url.openStream();
```

This is what I did.
The output is:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/SERVER/plugins/MyJar.jar!/test.txt
```

My InputStream always ends up throwing an IOException when being initialized, even though the URL is being output correctly.
So how is that possible?
Why can't I open the stream?

EDIT:
Also, please don't answer with "use getResourceAsStream", since it uses the same kind of code:

```
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
    URL url = getResource(name);
    try {
        return url != null ? url.openStream() : null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the message from the IOException? For that matter, does your jar have test.txt in its root directory?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I didn't read my stack traces after some changes to the code and it turns out that an invalid character in a file name caused the IOException, not the stream. Thanks a lot for the thought, I will now go and cry in shame.

Comment: Trust me when I say you're not the first person to miss messages in a Stack Trace. Not by a long shot. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would open it as a stream *directly* e.g.

```
InputStream  is = BlockConverter.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
```

The above method is the way I normally access resources within a jar (it will open the resource regardless of it being packaged within a jar, or simply as an unpackaged deployment, note)

Comment: I attempted it, but it resulted in the same thing. Besides that, I need to log the URL anyways so this seems like the cleaner solution.

Comment: Also note that getResourceAsStream() uses url.openStream() in its source code, so it makes no difference.

Comment: Where is test.txt in relation to BlockConverter ? The above would suggest it should be at the root of the jar file. If you're getting a null stream, I think your jar packaging or the reference to the entity is wrong

Comment: It is at the root of the jar file.